# Possible to assign a domain name an IP adress on a router?

Tags: networking, router, dns

Is it possible to assign a fixed adress for some hostname on a router? What I mean is not to assign IP adresses to a local machine, rather to sepcify an adress for some specific host (like google.com) so that it returns to all my local network the specified IP.

On a server machine I would add an entry in the hosts file, but how can I do this on a router? I'm running the ASUS-RT-N66U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That router, running stock firmware, won't have the ability to edit the hosts file of the device. If it were running open firmware you might depending on the firmware. The best you can do is edit the hosts files of all the computers you need to redirect.

Comment: That's the problem. It's a Samsung TV, so I can't modify it there. :(

Comment: Would it be possible to use my Windows laptop as DNS server for the TV? I can specify the DNS on the TV, but how can I make my laptop act as the DNS? Is it enough to enter the IP in my local host file and give the IP as the DNS? Probalby not.

Comment: That'll be an involved process. Setting up BIND or Windows Server's DNS software is not the most trivial thing. You have to setup a DNS server to serve requests on your network (Manually set the DNS server on router to the server you setup in your LAN). You have to set the server up to go out on the internet and make DNS requests that it can't satisfy. You have to configure the DNS server to NEVER update its DNS Cache because this will overwrite the DNS entry that you explicitly set. Even then, the DNS server might be hardcoded into the TV (as is the case with Android phones).